# SUBQUERY com group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, mysqli

Tenho esta consulta `sql` porém meu agrupamento está me retornando valores que não conferem (como se ele ignorasse).

Na coluna da subconsulta ele duplica a resposta do valor de cima, porém o valor correto deveria ser nulo.

```
SELECT T.DATA_EMISSAO,
       COUNT(T.ID) COUNT_TITULO,
       SUM(T.VALOR) as SOMA_VALOR,
       COUNT(C.CPF) AS COUNT_CPF,
       (SELECT SUM(T.VALOR) AS RECEBIDO 
           FROM TITULO T
           INNER JOIN CLIENTE C on T.CODIGO_CLIENTE = C.CODIGO_CLIENTE
           WHERE T.EMPRESA_ID = 1
             AND T.SITUACAO = 'RECEBIDO'
             AND T.DATA_EMISSAO between '2020-12-19' and '2021-01-01')
FROM TITULO T
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C on T.CODIGO_CLIENTE = C.CODIGO_CLIENTE
WHERE T.EMPRESA_ID = 1
  AND T.DATA_EMISSAO between '2020-12-19' and '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY T.DATA_EMISSAO
```

Answer (score -3):

Segue uma possível solução utilizando a instrução `CASE` como argumento da função `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT
    T.DATA_EMISSAO
   ,COUNT(T.ID)  AS 'COUNT_TITULO'
   ,SUM(T.VALOR) AS 'SOMA_VALOR'
   ,COUNT(C.CPF) AS 'COUNT_CPF'
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.SITUACAO = 'RECEBIDO' THEN T.VALOR ELSE 0 END) AS 'RECEBIDO'
FROM TITULO T
   INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON T.CODIGO_CLIENTE = C.CODIGO_CLIENTE
WHERE T.EMPRESA_ID = 1
   AND T.DATA_EMISSAO BETWEEN '2020-12-19' AND '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY
T.DATA_EMISSAO
```

Poderias tratar essa query de diversas outras formas, com CTE ou `OUTER`/`CROSS APPLY`, porém tem que testar em seu ambiente.

Cuidado com filtros do tipo `DATETIME` com `BETWEEN`, pois se tiver hora neste campo sua expressão não filtrará os registros que tiver hora no seu argumento final da data.

Answer (score -3):

A cada resultado existente a subquery será "reexecutada", pois ela está se comportando como uma de suas colunas da consulta principal.
Uma alternativa seria atrelar um valor da consulta principal na condição da subquery.

```sql
SELECT T.DATA_EMISSAO
     , COUNT(T.ID) COUNT_TITULO
     , SUM(T.VALOR) as SOMA_VALOR
     , COUNT(C.CPF) AS COUNT_CPF
     , (
        SELECT SUM(T1.VALOR) AS RECEBIDO
          FROM TITULO T1
         INNER JOIN CLIENTE C on T1.CODIGO_CLIENTE = C.CODIGO_CLIENTE
         WHERE T1.EMPRESA_ID = 1
           AND T1.SITUACAO = 'RECEBIDO'
           AND T1.DATA_EMISSAO between '2020-12-19' and '2021-01-01'
           AND T1.ID = T.ID ---> ATRELANDO SUBQUERY À CONSULTA PRINCIPAL
        )
  FROM TITULO T
 INNER JOIN CLIENTE C on T.CODIGO_CLIENTE = C.CODIGO_CLIENTE
 WHERE T.EMPRESA_ID = 1
   AND T.DATA_EMISSAO between '2020-12-19' and '2021-01-01'
 GROUP BY T.DATA_EMISSAO
```